# How to "undo" (revert) Ctrl+L in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, location-bar

I'm on 12.04 Desktop.  When browsing the file system, it's convenient to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> so as to get the file path "Location" to render as a string; I can then modify the file path or even paste something in and get redirected right where I want to go.

But often, after typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, I find myself wanting to revert back to the normal way Nautilus renders the file path (as a series of buttons/links). What's the magical shortcut to "**undo**" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and go back to "**normal mode**"? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just press <kbd>esc</kbd>. Also make sure that location bar is focused while pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 13):

Focus the address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> :)

Comment: Or esc, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can also press <kbd>Enter</kbd> with the same or a different path.
It will change back to the normal button mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** What you want to do is push the <kbd>/</kbd> key to type in an address. After you type it in, it will automatically revert to the pathbar (which is called 'breadcrumbs', by the way).

---

To permanently change it, open a terminal and type:

> gconf-editor

On the left hand side, expand `apps`, `nautilus`, then click on `preferences`.

Now on the right-hand side, check / uncheck `always_use_location_entry`.

Comment: always_use_location_entry is unchecked. 

I'm talking about then I have the pathbar, but want to temporarily switch to the addressbar (to copy a path etc) and then switch back to the pathbar.

Comment: @ssanj: There. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Using / does not seem to work with Lucid. I have to use CTRL+L.

Comment: @ssanj: I have Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid) and just tried it. By the way, the addressbar / pathbar must not be selected. Try clicking in the folder's contents and then pressing '/'.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I'm running 2.6.32-24-generic #38-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux, Nautilus 2.30.1

Comment: @ssanj: According to `uname`, I'm running `"2.6.32-23-generic #37-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux"` and Nautilus 2.30.1

Answer (score 0):

**Don't get Confused :)**

You press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> and shown directory path.

then looses focus and try to press other keys to get rid of it. so

**->>> Click on address bar and press** <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Absolute Directory Path is shown]